# Clear error message or reset validation using jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am a newbie to jQuery and I aplogize if this question is very basic.

I am using *bassistance's Valiation* plugin to validate a simple form. One of the text fields is mandatory - so I set **required** flag under *rules* and a corresponding message under *messages*. The problem I have is, once the validation kicks in, the error message I've set is displayed even if the field is blank (meaning, if the user deletes the contents of the field to start from scratch). Is there anyway to clear the error message or reset the validation if the field becomes empty? I tried to use the resetForm(), but looks like I can't use it while it's still validating. Here's part of the code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  var validator = $("#form1").validate({
     rules: {
         fname: {
             required: true,
             remote: 'http://localhost/check_name.php'  
         }
       },
     messages: {
         fname: {
             required: "Enter a valid jobname. eg: 99999_Disney",
             remote: "Name already exists";
                    }   

               } 
  });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I solved the problem. Not sure if it's the most elegant way to do it, but it works. I had to clear the invalid state of the field somehow. I tried `resetForm()` but that didn't work. In the end I used something like this `{ validator.resetForm();
                    $("#ID").rules("remove", "minlength required");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Not sure if it's the most elegant way to do it, but it works. I had to clear the invalid state of the field somehow. I tried `resetForm()` but that didn't work. In the end I used something like this:

```
if ($("#ID").val()=="") {
                validator.resetForm();
                $("#ID").rules("remove", "required minlength");
        }
```

and as needed added those rules back to the ID using:

```
$("#ID").rules("add", {
                             required: true,
                             minlength: 5,    
                             messages: {//messages
                             },                             
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a validation method, like so:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ValReqJobName", valReqJobName, "Enter a valid jobname.");
```

And then, in the rules object, under "fname", just add "ValReqJobName: true".

Within the "valReqJobName" function you can allow for the field to be blank, or add whatever custom logic you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your idea but I can't get it to work, and I feel like my logic is flawed. Here's what I am trying to accomplish: I want the field to be required or mandatory, but not display the error if the field is just blank. After the plugin starts validating the field, it always displays the message for "required" - even the field is empty and the field does not have focus. So I wrote something like this, but it's flawed:

Comment: `jQuery.validator.addMethod(  
      "namereq",  
      function(jname) {  
       var focusflag = false;  
       jname.focus(function() {  
         focusflag = true;  
       }  
       jname.blur(function() {  
         focusflag = false;  
       }         
       if ((focusflag == true) && (jname.length == 0))  
        {  
          return true;  
        }  
        else return false;  
      },  
      "Not empty."  
    );` Could you take a look at this please?

Comment: i apologize, i can't figure out how to post a code in the comments section